# Casting getActivity() to parent activity giving error in sdk 23

Tags: android, android-fragments

After updating to *`SDK 23`* . when I am trying to cast **`getActivity()`** in fragment to parent activity it is giving error. But it was working fine with previous *`SDK's`*.

Code is: `((MyActivity) getActivity()).methodInActivity();`

Error is:

```
inconvertible types cannot cast android.app.activity to com.myapp.myactivity.
```

why this error showing?

Comment: Can you show the line where you use `getActivity()`?

Comment: put your `cast` code

Comment: Issue fixed? Put some code where and how you use it?

Comment: I deleted built files and restarted studio, error gone. This is silly.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
((YourContainerActivity) getActivity()).yourMethodInActivity();
```

Comment: *inconvertible types cannot cast* I think casting is alredy done... but not working by change of inheritance in sdk23....

Comment: @JordiCastilla  and Kavessh I deleted built files and restarted studio, error gone. Silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Although I updated my solution via comments long ago but today got one more up-vote on this question so thought I should add the answer, many times we get this type of unusual errors in android studio so before looking on web we should first check with **deleting build files and restarting android studio** in most the cases this solution work.